# 301 Redirect Rule gives different results on different hosting environment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I have been doing some URL rewriting for a customer in a test environment that work fine in my environment but when I move to theirs I get different results and the rule fails.

I am 301 redirecting legacy dynamic URLs in the following format:

```
http://www.companyname.com/page.php?pagename=AboutCompany&lang=EN
to
http://www.companyname.com/EN/about-company/
```

Using the ruleset below this works fine on my 'Heart Internet' shared hosting but fails on their 'Go Daddy' shared hosting (configs below). On the Go Daddy environment the legacy URL gets redirected to:

```
http://www.companyname.com/GET/about-company/
instead of
http://www.companyname.com/EN/about-company/
```

where does the 'GET' come? This is a barebones page with no other code influencing these rules.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pagename=AboutCompany
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /page.php
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /%1/about-company/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/about-company$ page.php?pagename=AboutCompany&lang=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/about-company/$ page.php?pagename=AboutCompany&lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

The 'lang' querystring differs depending on the user language preference (EN or FR or DE etc...)

**Test Enviroment:** 
Windows  
IIS7.5  
PHP 5.3.6

**Customer Enviroment:**  
Linux  
Apache  
PHP 5.2

Thanks, M.

Comment: IIS's rewrite engine isn't the same as apache's

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks, I know that they are different, hence why I listed the environments. Still, I'd like to know how I can get the same behaviour in the apache environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where does the 'GET' come? This is a barebones page with no other code influencing these rules.

In this snippet of your rules, you have a backreference **`%1`** in your `RewriteRule`. This references the last `()` match in the previous `RewriteCond`, which happens to be `(GET|HEAD)`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /page.php
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /%1/about-company/? [R=301,L]
```

You want to switch those 2 conditions around:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /page.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /%1/about-company/? [R=301,L]
```

So that the **`%1`** references `([^&]+)`

Comment: Or try making `(GET|HEAD)` as not-referenced (so it cannot be back referenced by %N): `(?:GET|HEAD)` -- such approach is considered more safer (as order or conditions does not matter here at all)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Jon and Lazy. This is now resolved. I thought that %1 look at the first condition not the last match. I had thought that might be where the get came from but given my understanding (or lack of) this did not seem right. Thanks Again.